# Why is sunlight not violet in color?

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun

I have a UV lamp which appears violet in color, but our own sun also emits UV rays so where does the violet go? Why does sunlight not appear violet?

Comment: @JohnRennie That relates to Rayleigh scattering. This question is on the color of the sun, not the rest of the sky. (I did look for a duplicate, but given my user name, I'm quite happy to answer :) )

Comment: @BlackbodyBlacklight: ah, yes, OK I'll withdraw the close vote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the radiation of the sun is black-body radiation, which is to say, the sun is bright because it is hot. As an object heats up (think of a furnace), it glows dim red, then bright red, orange, yellow, and then white. Why not green? Because a black body spectrum isn't monochromatic, it's broad.

[image: Black body color temperature]
(From [Wikipedia: Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature).)

Our eyes are adapted for sensitivity to the spectral range of sunlight, which is why the whitest shade in the above diagram occurs at 6000K, the temperature of the surface of the sun. Although UV rays are part of white sunlight, they are the minority.

Note that the bluer shades occur at much higher temperatures, and the color swatch starts getting darker over 20,000K as they outweigh the balance of the visible colors. Such temperatures are needed for black-body blacklights. When you see a star that appears blue in the sky, it's much brighter than it appears, because most of the light is UV which you can't see — just like your tabletop lamp.

Answer (score 0):

Sun appears as yellow or orange is only because its short-wavelength colours (green, blue, violet) are scattered out by the Earth's atmosphere. 
So only the colours which have larger wavelengths are perceived by our eyes.